# How to check if a certain string is contained within an array returned by JSON_QUERY

Tags: json, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to write a SQL statement that will parse some JSON and return only rows where one of the arrays in the JSON Object contains a given value.

Example JSON:

```
Object 1:
{
  "Key1": ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
}

Object 2:
{
  "Key1": ["item1", "item3"]
}
```

I would like to only return rows where `JSON_QUERY(object, '$.Key1').Contains("item2")` is true (in this example, Object 1).

Of course, this magical function 'Contains()' does not exist in tsql, and I can't find any documentation of a function that performs as I'd like.

EDIT:
My current solution (which I'm not very fond of and would like to replace) checks if the string literal `'"item1"'` is contained within the value returned by JSON_QUERY. I don't like this, because it's possible an entry in the array could have a value like `'123123"item1"123123'`, and then the conditional would return true.

Answer (score 0):

Christian,

Sounds to me like your SQL Query could use a where clause using a LIKE comparison on a column

```
WHERE col1 LIKE 'some%funky%string'
```

The % is a wildcard declaritive

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OPENJSON` to get a derived result set out of a json list or array:

The followin query uses `JSON_QUERY` to retrieve the list of strings within `Key1`. This is passed as argument into `OPENJSON` to retrive the list of strings as derived table:

```
DECLARE @jsonTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, JsonString NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @jsonTable VALUES
 (N'{
  "Key1": ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
    }')
,(N'{
  "Key1": ["item1", "item3"]
    }');

DECLARE @LookFor NVARCHAR(100)='Item2'

SELECT jt.ID
      ,jt.JsonString
      ,A.value
FROM @jsonTable jt
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(jt.JsonString,N'$.Key1')) AS A
--WHERE A.value=@LookFor
```

Uncomment the final `WHERE` to reduce the list to the rows with a value of `Item2` (as defined in the variable `@LookFor`).